# как очистить root от ненужных файлов в UBUNTU?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем привет. Недавно поставил Ubuntu как вторую ОС. На Ubuntu было выделено 202 ГБ из них 15 ГБ на системные файлы, как я понимаю это root. Я решил установить через терминал openCV, tensorflow, cmake и у меня при включении стало появляться сообщение что из 15 ГБ свободных осталось 600 Мб, а позже вообще перестал подгружаться Ubuntu из-за не хватки памяти, хотя все что я устанавливал, я видел в домашней папке. Подскажите, могу ли я это как-то исправить или нужно Ubuntu устанавливать заново?

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно, куда делись  202 ГБ

Comment: @user7860670 я интерпретирую текст вопроса так: был диск грубо говоря 220 ГБ, при установке ОС его разбили на разделы, 15 ГБ - под систему, ~200ГБ под home. Системе в какой-то момент стало тесно в своем разделе (может вообще описанные в вопросе действия пользователя никак не это не повлияли, а тупо 10 ГБ обновлений скачалось).

Comment: `ncdu`? `gdu`? `baobab`? Ну и потом чистить согласно документации конкретного пакетного менеджера.